# CordovaActivity with Workmanager observe

Tags: android, cordova, android-workmanager

I have a CordovaActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
```

I am trying to make use of a WorkManager Livedata as shown below

```
 WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(TAG_NAME)
                .observe( HOW_CAN_I_PASS_LIFECYCLEOBJECT_?, workStatus -> {
                    if (workStatus == null) {
                    }
                 });
```

I am not sure what to pass on the first argument of observe i.e. at "HOW_CAN_I_PASS_LIFECYCLEOBJECT_?" ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean `LifeCycleOwner` right ?
In this case, `LifeCycleOwner` interface is implemented with an activity.
So in this case, you will pass the activity to `HOW_CAN_I_PASS_LIFECYCLEOBJECT`

Comment: Hi Damii, you mean 'CordovaActivity'?